# 4 kbytes getting stuck in RemotThread

Tags: delphi, winapi, memory, memory-management

I use this snippet to inject just a little function to a remote process like this:

```
function InjectMemory(Process: LongWord; Memory: pointer; Len: longword): pointer;
var
  BytesWritten: longword;
begin
  Result := VirtualAllocEx(Process, nil, Len, MEM_COMMIT or MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
  WriteProcessMemory(Process, Result, Memory, Len, BytesWritten);
end;

function MyFunc ( p : pointer ) : Integer; stdcall;
begin end;

var
 PHandle        : Cardinal;
 RemoteThreadID : Cardinal;
begin
 pHandle := OpenProcess (PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, 1234)
 if pHandle <> 0 then
  pThreadAddress := InjectMemory (pHandle, @MyThread, SizeOfProc(@MyThread)); 
  CreateRemoteThread (pHandle, nil, 0, pThreadAddress, nil, 0, RemoteThreadID);
  CloseHandle (pHandle)
 end;
end;
```

The SizeOfProc function :

```
uses
  Windows, sysutils;

function SizeOfCode(Code: pointer): integer;
function SizeOfProc(Proc: pointer): integer;

implementation

const
  Opcodes1: array [0..255] of word =
  (
    (16913),(17124),(8209),(8420),(33793),(35906),(0),(0),(16913),(17124),(8209),(8420),(33793),(35906),(0),(0),(16913),
    (17124),(8209),(8420),(33793),(35906),(0),(0),(16913),(17124),(8209),(8420),(33793),(35906),(0),(0),(16913),
    (17124),(8209),(8420),(33793),(35906),(0),(32768),(16913),(17124),(8209),(8420),(33793),(35906),(0),(32768),(16913),
    (17124),(8209),(8420),(33793),(35906),(0),(32768),(529),(740),(17),(228),(1025),(3138),(0),(32768),(24645),
    (24645),(24645),(24645),(24645),(24645),(24645),(24645),(24645),(24645),(24645),(24645),(24645),(24645),(24645),(24645),(69),
    (69),(69),(69),(69),(69),(69),(69),(24645),(24645),(24645),(24645),(24645),(24645),(24645),(24645),(0),
    (32768),(228),(16922),(0),(0),(0),(0),(3072),(11492),(1024),(9444),(0),(0),(0),(0),(5120),
    (5120),(5120),(5120),(5120),(5120),(5120),(5120),(5120),(5120),(5120),(5120),(5120),(5120),(5120),(5120),(1296),
    (3488),(1296),(1440),(529),(740),(41489),(41700),(16913),(17124),(8209),(8420),(17123),(8420),(227),(416),(0),
    (57414),(57414),(57414),(57414),(57414),(57414),(57414),(32768),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(32768),(33025),
    (33090),(769),(834),(0),(0),(0),(0),(1025),(3138),(0),(0),(32768),(32768),(0),(0),(25604),
    (25604),(25604),(25604),(25604),(25604),(25604),(25604),(27717),(27717),(27717),(27717),(27717),(27717),(27717),(27717),(17680),
    (17824),(2048),(0),(8420),(8420),(17680),(19872),(0),(0),(2048),(0),(0),(1024),(0),(0),(16656),
    (16800),(16656),(16800),(33792),(33792),(0),(32768),(8),(8),(8),(8),(8),(8),(8),(8),(5120),
    (5120),(5120),(5120),(33793),(33858),(1537),(1602),(7168),(7168),(0),(5120),(32775),(32839),(519),(583),(0),
    (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(8),(8),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(16656),(416)
  );

  Opcodes2: array [0..255] of word =
  (
    (280),(288),(8420),(8420),(65535),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(65535),(65535),(65535),(272),(0),(1325),(63),
    (575),(63),(575),(63),(63),(63),(575),(272),(65535),(65535),(65535),(65535),(65535),(65535),(65535),(16419),
    (16419),(547),(547),(65535),(65535),(65535),(65535),(63),(575),(47),(575),(61),(61),(63),(63),(0),
    (32768),(32768),(32768),(0),(0),(65535),(65535),(65535),(65535),(65535),(65535),(65535),(65535),(65535),(65535),(8420),
    (8420),(8420),(8420),(8420),(8420),(8420),(8420),(8420),(8420),(8420),(8420),(8420),(8420),(8420),(8420),(16935),
    (63),(63),(63),(63),(63),(63),(63),(63),(63),(63),(63),(63),(63),(63),(63),(237),
    (237),(237),(237),(237),(237),(237),(237),(237),(237),(237),(237),(237),(237),(101),(237),(1261),
    (1192),(1192),(1192),(237),(237),(237),(0),(65535),(65535),(65535),(65535),(65535),(65535),(613),(749),(7168),
    (7168),(7168),(7168),(7168),(7168),(7168),(7168),(7168),(7168),(7168),(7168),(7168),(7168),(7168),(7168),(16656),
    (16656),(16656),(16656),(16656),(16656),(16656),(16656),(16656),(16656),(16656),(16656),(16656),(16656),(16656),(16656),(0),
    (0),(32768),(740),(18404),(17380),(49681),(49892),(0),(0),(0),(17124),(18404),(17380),(32),(8420),(49681),
    (49892),(8420),(17124),(8420),(8932),(8532),(8476),(65535),(65535),(1440),(17124),(8420),(8420),(8532),(8476),(41489),
    (41700),(1087),(548),(1125),(9388),(1087),(33064),(24581),(24581),(24581),(24581),(24581),(24581),(24581),(24581),(65535),
    (237),(237),(237),(237),(237),(749),(8364),(237),(237),(237),(237),(237),(237),(237),(237),(237),
    (237),(237),(237),(237),(237),(63),(749),(237),(237),(237),(237),(237),(237),(237),(237),(65535),
    (237),(237),(237),(237),(237),(237),(237),(237),(237),(237),(237),(237),(237),(237),(0)
  );

  Opcodes3: array [0..9] of array [0..15] of word =
  (
    ((1296),(65535),(16656),(16656),(33040),(33040),(33040),(33040),(1296),(65535),(16656),(16656),(33040),(33040),(33040),(33040)),
    ((3488),(65535),(16800),(16800),(33184),(33184),(33184),(33184),(3488),(65535),(16800),(16800),(33184),(33184),(33184),(33184)),
    ((288),(288),(288),(288),(288),(288),(288),(288),(54),(54),(48),(48),(54),(54),(54),(54)),
    ((288),(65535),(288),(288),(272),(280),(272),(280),(48),(48),(0),(48),(0),(0),(0),(0)),
    ((288),(288),(288),(288),(288),(288),(288),(288),(54),(54),(54),(54),(65535),(0),(65535),(65535)),
    ((288),(65535),(288),(288),(65535),(304),(65535),(304),(54),(54),(54),(54),(0),(54),(54),(0)),
    ((296),(296),(296),(296),(296),(296),(296),(296),(566),(566),(48),(48),(566),(566),(566),(566)),
    ((296),(65535),(296),(296),(272),(65535),(272),(280),(48),(48),(48),(48),(48),(48),(65535),(65535)),
    ((280),(280),(280),(280),(280),(280),(280),(280),(566),(566),(48),(566),(566),(566),(566),(566)),
    ((280),(65535),(280),(280),(304),(296),(304),(296),(48),(48),(48),(48),(0),(54),(54),(65535))
  );

function SizeOfCode(Code: pointer): integer;
var
  Opcode: word;
  Modrm: byte;
  Fixed, AddressOveride: boolean;
  Last, OperandOveride, Flags, Rm, Size, Extend: longword;
begin
  try
    Last := longword(Code);
    if Code <> nil then
    begin
      AddressOveride := False;
      Fixed := False;
      OperandOveride := 4;
      Extend := 0;
      repeat
        Opcode := byte(Code^);
        Code := pointer(longword(Code) + 1);
        if Opcode = $66 then
        begin
          OperandOveride := 2;
        end
        else if Opcode = $67 then
        begin
          AddressOveride := True;
        end
        else
        begin
          if not ((Opcode and $E7) = $26) then
          begin
            if not (Opcode in [$64..$65]) then
            begin
              Fixed := True;
            end;
          end;
        end;
      until Fixed;
      if Opcode = $0f then
      begin
        Opcode := byte(Code^);
        Flags := Opcodes2[Opcode];
        Opcode := Opcode + $0f00;
        Code := pointer(longword(Code) + 1);
      end
      else
      begin
        Flags := Opcodes1[Opcode];
      end;
      if ((Flags and $0038) <> 0) then
      begin
        Modrm := byte(Code^);
        Rm := Modrm and $7;
        Code := pointer(longword(Code) + 1);
        case (Modrm and $c0) of
          $40: Size := 1;
          $80:
            begin
              if AddressOveride then
              begin
                Size := 2;
              end
              else
                Size := 4;
              end;
          else
          begin
            Size := 0;
          end;
        end;
        if not (((Modrm and $c0) <> $c0) and AddressOveride) then
        begin
          if (Rm = 4) and ((Modrm and $c0) <> $c0) then
          begin
            Rm := byte(Code^) and $7;
          end;
          if ((Modrm and $c0 = 0) and (Rm = 5)) then
          begin
            Size := 4;
          end;
          Code := pointer(longword(Code) + Size);
        end;
        if ((Flags and $0038) = $0008) then
        begin
          case Opcode of
            $f6: Extend := 0;
            $f7: Extend := 1;
            $d8: Extend := 2;
            $d9: Extend := 3;
            $da: Extend := 4;
            $db: Extend := 5;
            $dc: Extend := 6;
            $dd: Extend := 7;
            $de: Extend := 8;
            $df: Extend := 9;
          end;
          if ((Modrm and $c0) <> $c0) then
          begin
            Flags := Opcodes3[Extend][(Modrm shr 3) and $7];
          end
          else
          begin
            Flags := Opcodes3[Extend][((Modrm shr 3) and $7) + 8];
          end;
        end;
      end;
      case (Flags and $0C00) of
        $0400: Code := pointer(longword(Code) + 1);
        $0800: Code := pointer(longword(Code) + 2);
        $0C00: Code := pointer(longword(Code) + OperandOveride);
        else
        begin
          case Opcode of
            $9a, $ea: Code := pointer(longword(Code) + OperandOveride + 2);
            $c8: Code := pointer(longword(Code) + 3);
            $a0..$a3:
              begin
                if AddressOveride then
                begin
                  Code := pointer(longword(Code) + 2)
                end
                else
                begin
                  Code := pointer(longword(Code) + 4);
                end;
              end;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
    Result := longword(Code) - Last;
  except
    Result := 0;
  end;
end;

function SizeOfProc(Proc: pointer): integer;
var
  Length: longword;
begin
  Result := 0;
  repeat
    Length := SizeOfCode(Proc);
    Inc(Result, Length);
    if ((Length = 1) and (byte(Proc^) = $C3)) then Break;
    Proc := pointer(longword(Proc) + Length);
  until Length = 0;
end;
```

The RemoteThread works just fine. But I can see that there are still 4 kbytes (or bytes?!) after the thread should be freed. Is there something I am missing?!

Comment: "But I can see that there are still 4 kbytes (or bytes?!) after the thread should be freed." Can you explain that part in detail please.

Comment: I looked into the taskmanager and saw that every time the thread get's created (actually after you allocate the memory) it get's 4 more kbytes (for example a process had 296kbytes it then has 300kbytes)

Comment: Can you show the code which deallocates the memory, and how it is called? That's the code that calls `VirtualFree`.

Comment: I use VirtualFreeEx and it seems to work now, but my process closes BEFORE the thread does. How am I supposed to free it then? :\

Comment: Yes, my mistake, `VirtualFree` is not good because this is in another process

Comment: Is there a non-evil reason for using code injection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are not calling `VirtualFreeEx` and so the memory is not being freed. If you want to free it then you clearly will need to call `VirtualFreeEx`. However, you'd need to wait until the remote thread was signaled before doing so.

In a comment you say:

> My process closes before the thread does. How am I supposed to free it then?

Well, that will present a challenge! One suggestion is that you don't attempt to free this memory at all. Instead that would make sure that you allocate it once only. You are allocating the memory every time you create a thread. Change that policy to allocate the memory once and then re-use it for each subsequent thread that you create.

The alternative to this is to make sure that your process waits for the remote thread, and then deallocates. Do that by calling `WaitForSingleObject` on the remote thread handle. Note that the remote thread handle is the return value from `CreateRemoteThread`. You currently ignore it.